# Permissions to upload InfoPath form to document library

Tags: 2013, document-library, infopath

I have an InfoPath form that has been published to a file share. Users fill out this form using the InfoPath client and print it. There is no need to store any data.

Now I have the requirement to add this form to a SharePoint document library (not a form library). As an owner of a team site in SP 2013 I'm able to upload the form but my site members get an error in the upload dialog "Sorry this site hasn't been shared with you".

What permissions are needed to upload an InfoPath form to a document library?

Comment: Do they fill the form locally on their environment and then they need to upload it to the document library?

Comment: No, they create the forms locally and need to upload them to the library. Other users then have to file out the forms locally and print them.

Comment: If they want to upload forms to the library, they would just need contribute permission on the library to do it. Do they have the permission level on it? How are they uploading the forms to it?